# How to Convert Coordinate Inputs to Negative or Positive Numbers With Texture Nodes

Tags: procedural, mathematics, shader-nodes

My goal is to make a procedural diamond plate texture, and I want to make it as simple as possible. So, if I can help it, I don't want to just duplicate my *Diamond-Shape* node group and angle it the other way.

In a nutshell, I want my *Vector Rotate* node to alternate rotating the diamonds by 45 or -45 degrees. I figured out a way to get 1 or -1 based on an odd or even input using this equation: *2(x % 2) - 1* (you can see my best node representation of the equation in the Value-Alternate node group).

The problem is, I don't know where I get *x*, or my input.
In other words, I don't know if I need an input node or if I need to do some math with the grid vector. I think I need to be able to adjust each diamond in the grid individually.
[image]

My complete node layout:
[image: My complete node layout]

*Diamond-Shape* node group:
[image: Diamond-Shape node group]

*Value-Alternate* node group:
[image: Value-Alternate node group]

Here's a reference:
[image]

Comment: I don't know of any way to do it without duplicating the diamond shape group. This is what I managed to do with it https://imgur.com/a/nirB2FB basically, i duplicated it, rotated it and gave it a bit of offset then mixed it with the original.

Comment: The reason is that if you (somehow) rotate every other one of your diamonds as you say, you won't get something like your reference.

Comment: As @mqbakamqbaka says, you have to do one of the following things: 1. Duplicate the node group, rotate the output of the second and mix them together with _Multiply_ or _Maximum_ for example, or 2. duplicate the node group, make it a single user and change the internal 45° to -45° and mix them together like mentioned before or 3. if you want a single node group, open the node group and edit it by duplicating the internal process thread, one for 45°, one for -45°, and mix them together inside the group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You will need to duplicate your diamond shape group**

The reason for that is that the pattern of your texture doesn't really match the pattern of the reference. Here is why :

This is how your texture looks now (our diamonds have a lightly different shape due to the Vector curves node that I couldn't reproduce exactly) :

[image]

If you rotate each other diamond like you said, you will get either of those two here :

[image]
[image]

And none of those really look like the reference. The reason is that you actually managed to reproduce "half" of the reference, see :

[image]

The other half is just like the first half but rotated and with a bit of offset.

This is how I would do it :

First, I modified a bit your diamond shape group so that we can rotate the diamonds. I did that by adding a Vector Rotate node before the Vector Curves :

[image]

I added the angle of the rotation and your Normalize node as an input of the group for convenience. The normalize node actually controls the size of the diamonds so I named the input "diamondSize".

Using this node group with an input angle of 90°, I got the rotated version of the diamonds :

[image]

I can then mix them with an Add Node :

[image]
[image]

They are overlapping because I haven't offset the second one yet. They need to be offset about half of your tiling size on X and Y, which can be done by just adding a Vector Math Add after the Scale Node at the beginning :

[image]

giving this :

[image]

But the diamonds are too big, but since I exposed the diamondSize, I can change it by setting it to `.15` instead of `.3` :

[image]
[image]

I can feed that to the bump node to have the result :

[image]

Now all that is left to do is tweak the Vector Curves to shape the diamonds to your liking :

[image]
[image]

**EDIT**

I'll also suggest you to invert the output of the group node before plugging it to the bump node because, right now (if I copied your node setup accurately), your diamonds are going downwards instead of going upwards (White is up and black is down).